# Add a meta content="noindex,nofollow" tag on a node created programmatically

Tags: nodes, meta-tags

Is it possible to add a meta content="noindex,nofollow" tag to the head on the page of a node created programmatically (and onl this node)? I have created the node like this:

```
function MODULENAME_install() {
  $bodytext = 'Some Text';

  $node = new stdClass(); 
  $node->type = "page"; 
  $node->title = "New title";
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
  node_object_prepare($node); 
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $bodytext;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = '';
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'full_html'; 
  $node->path = array('alias' => 'new-title');
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: You can add a variable and save the node id with this field. Check the current node having same id as variable then add meta tag.

Comment: yeah but i guess that i would have to get the nid of the created node inside the install function, but the add meta tag should probably go in another function.. or am i wrong? and what function should i use to add the meta tag, and can i then use the nid from the install function in the new function. Im sorry but i am new at module development.

Comment: When you save the node the nid will be returned so based on the returned nid you could do pass this to a function that will add the meta tag.

Comment: You can use `hook_preprocess_html`.

Comment: I have added this line after node save: $new_id = $node->nid;

and then added this function but it does not work..

function MODULENAME_preprocess_html(){
    if(arg(0) == "node" && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(1) == $new_id){
        $noindex = array(
            '#tag' => 'meta', 
            '#attributes' => array(
              'name' => 'robots', 
              'content' => 'noindex',
            )
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($noindex, 'noindex');
    }
}

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code for adding no-follow and no-index meta for the node. Put this code in your themes template.php file.

```
function MYTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'YOUR NODE NID' && !arg(2)) {
    $head_elements['MYMODULE_meta_robots'] = array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'robots',
        'content' => 'noindex'
      )
    );
  }
}
```